# How to make GraphicsGrid with content tight inside it?

Tags: programming

I am trying to use GraphicsGrid to typeset some labels for my plots. I found the labels look little better when I use GrapicsGrid vs Grid. The labels have equations in them and not just plain labels.

I just do not know how to make a GraphicsGrid which has no wasted space in it.

Here is an example using Grid, which does not have the problem of wasted space, and same example, using GraphicsGrid. Ps. in this example, I am using a nice little makeBoxes function I found on the net by P.J. Hinton  to make Derivatives in Traditionalform come out like they are in our textbook. Here is a [link to the original post if needed](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/d873b0489f0cca1/9226bb168c582879?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q=mathematica%20partial%20derivative%20traditionalForm#9226bb168c582879)

```
Remove["Global`*"];
MakeBoxes[Derivative[indices__][f_][vars__], TraditionalForm] := 
  SubscriptBox[MakeBoxes[f, TraditionalForm], 
   RowBox[Map[ToString, 
     Flatten[Thread[dummyhead[{vars}, Partition[{indices}, 1]]] /. 
       dummyhead -> Table]]]];

title = 2 Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t] == 
   1.1 Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] + 80 Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t];

title = Style[title, 16];

GraphicsGrid[{{Item[title, Alignment -> Top], SpanFromLeft}}, 
 ImageSize -> {150, 80}, Frame -> All, ImageMargins -> 0, 
 ImagePadding -> 0, BaselinePosition -> Center]
```

This gives

[image]

and using normal Grid, gives (noticed I had to call TraditionalForm once more here, but not with the above to get it to work)

```
Remove["Global`*"];
MakeBoxes[Derivative[indices__][f_][vars__], TraditionalForm] := 
  SubscriptBox[MakeBoxes[f, TraditionalForm], 
   RowBox[Map[ToString, 
     Flatten[Thread[dummyhead[{vars}, Partition[{indices}, 1]]] /. 
       dummyhead -> Table]]]];

tr = TraditionalForm;
title = 2 tr@Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t] == 
   1.1 tr@Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] + 80 tr@Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t];

title = Style[title, 16];
Grid[{{Item[title, Alignment -> Top], SpanFromLeft}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Played around with GraphicsGrid, but can't figure how to automatically tell it to put the object inside it as tight as possible. It will be best if I do not not specify `ImageSize`. But using `ImageSize-> Automatic` does not work:

```
GraphicsGrid[{{Item[title, Alignment -> Top], SpanFromLeft}}, 
 ImageSize -> Automatic, Frame -> All, ImageMargins -> 0, 
 ImagePadding -> 0, BaselinePosition -> Center]
```

[image]

Is there an option or a trick to do this?

thanks

Comment: Why not just use `PlotLabel` (or even `FrameLabel`) on the individual plots?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I prefer `Framed`. To improve labels just wrap `TraditionalForm` around it:

```
TraditionalForm@Framed[title]
```

[image]

If you have many cells and if the whole point is to make a tight grid and have nice labels, you could improve labels in `Grid`, rather then improving spacing in `GraphicsGrid`:

```
TraditionalForm[Grid[{{title}, {title}}, Frame -> All]]
```

[image]

`GraphicsGrid` is to handle graphics. Just for the sake of completeness you could simply `Rasterize` your formula to `Graphics` to make `GraphicsGrid` work:

```
GraphicsGrid[{{Rasterize@TraditionalForm[title]}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]